# Using Spawn-Expect mechanism in TCL-8.5

Tags: tcl, expect

```
set pipeline [open "|Certify.exe args" "r"]
fconfigure $pipeline -blocking false
fconfigure $pipeline -buffering none
fileevent $pipeline readable [list handlePipeReadable $pipeline]


proc handlePipeReadable {pipe} {
if {[gets $pipe line] >= 0} {
# Managed to actually read a line; stored in $line now
} elseif {[eof $pipe]} {
    # Pipeline was closed; get exit code, etc.
    if {[catch {close $pipe} msg opt]} {
        set exitinfo [dict get $opt -errorcode]
    } else {
        # Successful termination
        set exitinfo ""
    }
    # Stop the waiting in [vwait], below
    set ::donepipe $pipe
} else {
    puts ""
    # Partial read; things will be properly buffered up for now...
    }
}

vwait ::donepipe
```

I have tried using pipe in TCL code. But for some reason, I want to convert this to Spawn- Expect mechanism. But I am grappling with it and facing issues when doing so. Can anyone please help me out??

Comment: What issues? Show your expect code.

Comment: spawn "Certify.exe $parameters(0) $parameters(1) $parameters(2) $parameters(3) $parameters(4) $parameters(5) $parameters(6) $parameters(7) $parameters(8) $parameters(9) $parameters(10) $parameters(11) $parameters(12) $parameters(13) $parameters(14) $parameters(15)"

Comment: After using the spawn, while closing and opening the instance of the application I am getting error occured while loading the Java VM

Comment: Also I have not used expect as I did not now how to use expect in this context

Answer (score 1):

Expect makes the pattern of usage very different *and* it uses a different way of interacting with the wrapped program that's much more like how interactive usage works (which stops a whole class of buffering-related bugs, which I suspect may be what you're hitting). Because of that, converting things over is *not* a drop-in change. Here's the basic pattern of use *in a simple case:*

```
package require Expect

# Note: different words become different arguments here
spawn Certify.exe args

expect "some sort of prompt string"
send "your input\r";   # \r is *CARRIAGE RETURN*
expect "something else"
send "something else\r"
expect eof

close
```

The real complexity comes when you can set up timeouts, wait for multiple things at once, wait for patterns as well as literal strings, etc. But doing the same from ordinary Tcl (even ignoring the buffering problems) is much more work. It's also almost always more work in virtually every other language.

Note that Expect *doesn't* do GUI automation. Just command-line programs. GUI automation is a much more complex topic.

---

It's not possible to give generic descriptions of what might be done as it depends so much on what the `Certify.exe` program actually does, and how you work with it interactively.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Donal. I believe here that the problem is not from the Certify side. Because when I execute the Certify.exe args in the command prompt without TCL the script is triggered and completed successfully and the control is transferring back to the command prompt  correctly. Whereas when I use tclsh I am observing this issue which means that the root cause lies with the TCL right...Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding

Comment: Another question here is, you have used expect and send commands in your sample code.But whereas in my case, I just need to trigger my script. In this case, How can I make use of expect and send as  I do not input any text from the command prompt and do not expect anything either!!! Can u please clarify????

Comment: Vishal, I can't recall you ever saying how you have to interact with Certify? Are there  any prompts that you have to type some information into? Do you need to capture the output? Do you need to parse that output? Do you just want to launch it and forget about it?

Comment: Glenn,I will just call the certify.exe to trigger the actual script from test engine (Written in TCL) and after the script execution is completed the control should come back to the Test Engine.Thats all what my requirement is. Moreover we have used test engine to facilitate batch execution of the scripts which have been written with the help of the tool Worksoft Cerify.Hope this answered your query